# WPF MessageBox not working

Tags: wpf, messagebox

In my WPF I've tried `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show`, `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show`, and `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show`  (from the Wpf Toolkit).

Every one of these methods shows the message box exactly how I want it too. The problem is that none of the buttons work. I click `OK`, I click `cancel`, I click the `X`, none of the buttons do anything. And with the toolkit message box I can't move the message box either. The buttons don't depress either. It's as if they're disabled, but I have no idea why.

EDIT: I'm using Prism and MEF to compose the application. Inside my module I have a view that is being displayed in a region in my Shell Window. The view is a UserControl with a button.

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <Button content="click me" Click="Button_OnClick"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind I have the OnClick method.

```
private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

The message box gets displayed, I can move it, The 'X' glows on mouse over, but neither the 'X' nor the 'OK' button, do anything.

I can provide more code as needed, I just don't want to have to include my whole application...

**FIXED**
The main WPF window had a borderless behavior attached to it that was processing windows messages (WndProc) and it wasn't processing the WM_NCACTIVATE message properly.

NOT WORKING:

```
case UnsafeNativeConstants.WM_NCACTIVATE:
     handled = true;
     break;
```

WORKING:

```
case UnsafeNativeConstants.WM_NCACTIVATE:
     retVal = UnsafeNativeMethods.DefWindowProc(hwnd, UnsafeNativeConstants.WM_NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), new IntPtr(-1));
     handled = true;
     break;

internal static UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc([In] IntPtr hwnd, [In] int msg, [In] IntPtr wParam, [In] IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Comment: Strange... Without code it will hard to find problem source

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might prove a useful read.

Comment: Do you see this problem in the context of a new console application that only attempts to show a message box?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: I have a different app (A WinForm app) that uses System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox, and it works just fine, if that's what you're asking. It also works fine in a different WPF app I have.

Comment: Yes that was what I was asking. What happens if you pause VS when debugging the app with the dialog displayed? Is the message pump/loop still running?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Thank you so much! There was some code elsewhere that was fiddling with the windows message loop and it was causing the problem! I've been staring at this so long, sometimes it just takes a nudge in the right direction lol. If you post that in a comment (There was a behavior for creating a borderless window that was hooked to WndProc and causing the problem) I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your app in the debugger and pausing when the dialog is visible to ensure the message pump/loop is still running and is not deadlocked. That's the only reason I can think of that your UI could be unresponsive.